# Get information about parent categories

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

Short information about my environment:

1. Sitecore 8.2.1
2. Sitecore Commerce 8.2.0 (Initial Release)

Hi!

I need to implement a custom condition for promotions. I need to get information regarding the parents of a product (from a shopping cart) in this context.
I tried to find the solution and found at least 2 ways to get these data.

1. Use CatalogItemBase class like in was proposed in [this](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19354/get-sellable-items-in-category) thread. I tried to use a similar code, but it looks like I don't have this class in my `Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog dll` (too old version?).

```
    var source = await this._findEntityPipeline.Run(new FindEntityArgument(typeof(CatalogItemBase), arg.SourceName, false), context) as CatalogItemBase;
```

2. Get SellableItem from the context. I can see all the required products (which are included in the cart), however, they don't have any fields/ components which include information regarding parent items.

Do you know how to get this type of relations? Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Check this: https://www.xcentium.com/blog/2019/03/26/sxc-bizfx---sellableitem-parent-categories-view

It's for Commerce 9 but you can adapt it for 8.2.