# How to get sellable items from a catalog

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I'm just getting started with Sitecore Commerce (10.1) and having a tough time trying to figure out things.

From the sample solution in the Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.SDK, I understood that we need to refer the Sitecore.Commerce.ServiceProxy project. But I'm unable to go any further.

The catalog will have around 8000 items and I would like to display them on the webpage.
Could anyone please help me with any pointers or the code on how to get the list of sellable items.

Basically, any documentation which is a step by step guide would be much helpful.

Comment: Have you tried the answer from the question https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19354/get-sellable-items-in-category? For example var sellableItems = container.SellableItems.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();

Comment: @CristiVulturar Use the vote-to-close mechanic next time

Answer (score 2):

I found a block named `GetSellableItemsViewBlock` in which it is fetching all the Sellable Items

```
await sellableItemsViewBlock._findEntitiesInListPipeline.Run(new FindEntitiesInListArgument(typeof (SellableItem), string.Format("{0}", (object) CommerceEntity.ListName<SellableItem>()), 0, int.MaxValue), context))?.List?.Items
```

So you can use the above code to get all the sellable items.
You can dotpeek into GetSellableItemsViewBlock class, it's in `Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog.dll`

Comment: Thank you. Could you please share the complete method.